# Firefox Extension/Addon - Detect workspace locked

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm searching for a solution in my firefox addon to detect when the user workspace has locked/released. In google chrome there is an easy API `chrome.idle.onStateChanged.addListener` for it, is there something similar in firefox or any possibility to do that, platform independent?
By the way, I use the addon sdk.

I've already tried the idle service:

```
Cc["@mozilla.org/widget/idleservice;1"].getService(Ci.nsIIdleService)
```

but I just gives me access to some idle timeout or system when go to sleep and not to just workspace locked.

Edit: With "workspace locked" I mean the user lock the workspace with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd>. I don't know how this exactly work on OSX or linux.

Edit2: I working in Windows 8.1 currently, but I guess the `chrome.idle` handler works cross platform.

Edit3: What i currently get out of current answers is 
1. That there not exist a cross-platform solution, neither in chrome nor in firefox.
`chrome.idle.onStateChanged` seems to work different on windows, linux and osx. Only windows can handle that "locked" behaviour as expected. I can't test OSX, on ubuntu 14 it doesn't work for me.
2. For firefox there some in-depth code things to try to make it working - see answer bellow from Noitidart in this topic.

Edit4: Noitidart have found a solution for windows - [github link](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/06f79f17a8e8a2268a1e).

Comment: What do you mean by worksapce being locked? Like for windows if user locks the screen with ctrl+alt+del?

Comment: If nobody finds a solution, don't hesitate to file a bug on http://bugzilla.mozilla.org, in component `toolkit`, and add me (`:Yoric`) in the Cc list. I make no promise, but either the core devs or irregular contributors may be interested in working on this.

Comment: Thanks @Yoric I'm thinking i'll look up google chrome's sourcecode, like MXR or DXR and give this guy a js-ctypes solution until we get an XPCOM solution. Also if i find that code in google chrome then i can post it in the bugzilla topic, it sounds like a good first bug.

Comment: @BrianFooLong do you know what OS'es `chrome.idle` works in? Can you test for me? It looks like in mac it only triggers lock when screensaver is on. In windows it looks like it works right, when screen locked or screensaver running. In linux it looks like they dont support it at all. Can you please verify.

Comment: Actually it looks like mac supports screnlock as well. So windows and mac support screenlock and screensaver. What about linux? From the sourcecode it looks like there is no support for either, but im not sure, can you please verify. The docs to state anything about OS.

Comment: I edited below it looks like Linux does have support only for screensaver though. @BrainFooLong can you please verify that Linux is only screensaver. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to detect screen lock but there are these observer notifications:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications#Idle_Service

Also the computer sleep wake notifications. ill ask around for lock screen thats an interesting one.

Some useful chat about the subject, looking at how google chrome does it:

> [12:33]  ok guys question about actual work. anyone know how to detect if screen was locked? apparently google chrome has a method: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/idle#event-onStateChanged
>
> [12:45]  anyone know of a MXR or DXR for google chromes codebase?
>
> [12:46]  mxr.mozilla.org/chromium
>
> [12:52]  Ms2ger: can you help me find how they test screen lock. im looking here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/source/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/idle/idle_api_unittest.cc#84
>
> [12:56]  oh yuck it looks like they poll: http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/source/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/idle/idle_manager.h#118

maybe they arent polling.

check this out:

http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/source/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/idle/idle_manager.cc#246

```
244 void IdleManager::UpdateIdleStateCallback(int idle_time) {
245   DCHECK(thread_checker_.CalledOnValidThread());
246   bool locked = idle_time_provider_->CheckIdleStateIsLocked();
247   int listener_count = 0;
```

leads to: http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/source/src/chrome/browser/idle_win.cc#52

```
52 bool CheckIdleStateIsLocked() {
53   return ui::IsWorkstationLocked() || IsScreensaverRunning();
54 }
```

**so this leads us to test if screensaver running or workstation locked**

leads to:

- http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/search?string=IsWorkstationLocked

  - we see just one implementation *(its curious because there is no linux support but it doesnt say so on the chrome docs page, so maybe i couldnt find it)*

    - Windows

      - http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/source/src/ui/base/win/lock_state.cc#11

        ```
        11 bool IsWorkstationLocked() {
        12   bool is_locked = true;
        13   HDESK input_desk = ::OpenInputDesktop(0, 0, GENERIC_READ);
        14   if (input_desk) {
        15     wchar_t name[256] = {0};
        16     DWORD needed = 0;
        17     if (::GetUserObjectInformation(
        18             input_desk, UOI_NAME, name, sizeof(name), &needed)) {
        19       is_locked = lstrcmpi(name, L"default") != 0;
        20     }
        21     ::CloseDesktop(input_desk);
        22   }
        23   return is_locked;
        24 }
        ```
    - Mac

      - see the screensaver section below, the screenlock is handled via there as well
- http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/search?string=IsScreensaverRunning&find=&findi=&filter=^%5B^\0%5D*%24&hitlimit=&tree=chromium

  - we see in this search results 2 implementations, mac and windows *it looks like no support for linux, which is curious because the chrome.idle page doesnt mention this on docs, maybe i just couldnt find it*

    - windows implementation: http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/source/src/chrome/browser/idle_win.cc#39

      ```
      39 bool IsScreensaverRunning() {
      40   DWORD result = 0;
      41   if (::SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, 0, &result, 0))
      42     return result != FALSE;
      43   return false;
      44 }
      45
      ```
    - mac implementation: http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/source/src/chrome/browser/idle_mac.mm#28

      ```
      28 - (id)init {
      29   if ((self = [super init])) {
      30     NSDistributedNotificationCenter* distCenter =
      31           [NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
      32     [distCenter addObserver:self
      33                    selector:@selector(onScreenSaverStarted:)
      34                        name:@"com.apple.screensaver.didstart"
      35                      object:nil];
      36     [distCenter addObserver:self
      37                    selector:@selector(onScreenSaverStopped:)
      38                        name:@"com.apple.screensaver.didstop"
      39                      object:nil];
      40     [distCenter addObserver:self
      41                    selector:@selector(onScreenLocked:)
      42                        name:@"com.apple.screenIsLocked"
      43                      object:nil];
      44     [distCenter addObserver:self
      45                    selector:@selector(onScreenUnlocked:)
      46                        name:@"com.apple.screenIsUnlocked"
      47                      object:nil];
      48   }
      49   return self;
      50 }
      ```

so to sum this all up:

> [13:32]  for windows its peice of cake winapi has call to test if screen is locked or scrensaver running
>
> [13:32]  for mac they dont have screen lock test. they just have screensaver test, but its an observer method
>
> [13:32]  for linux they dont have screen lock nor screen saver test. real odd. ill ask the guy if he knows which os's they support chrome.idle in

edit: actually i found the linux implementation. back from the search results of: `CheckIdleStateLocked`: http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/search?string=CheckIdleStateIsLocked

- http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/source/src/chrome/browser/idle_linux.cc#24

  ```
  24 bool CheckIdleStateIsLocked() {
  25   // Usually the screensaver is used to lock the screen, so we do not need to
  26   // check if the workstation is locked.
  27 #if defined(OS_CHROMEOS)
  28   return false;
  29 #elif defined(USE_OZONE)
  30   return false;
  31 #else
  32   return ScreensaverWindowFinder::ScreensaverWindowExists();
  33 #endif
  34 }
  ```
- Leads to ask how is `ScreensaverWindowExists` we find this: http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/source/src/chrome/browser/screensaver_window_finder_x11.cc

  ```
  15 bool ScreensaverWindowFinder::ScreensaverWindowExists() {
  16   gfx::X11ErrorTracker err_tracker;
  17   ScreensaverWindowFinder finder;
  18   ui::EnumerateTopLevelWindows(&finder);
  19   return finder.exists_ && !err_tracker.FoundNewError();
  20 }
  ```
- Leads to what is `EnumerateTopLevelWindows` http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/source/src/ui/base/x/x11_util.cc#1059:

  ```
  1059 void EnumerateTopLevelWindows(ui::EnumerateWindowsDelegate* delegate) {
  1060   std::vector<XID> stack;
  1061   if (!ui::GetXWindowStack(ui::GetX11RootWindow(), &stack)) {
  1062     // Window Manager doesn't support _NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING, so fall back
  1063     // to old school enumeration of all X windows.  Some WMs parent 'top-level'
  1064     // windows in unnamed actual top-level windows (ion WM), so extend the
  1065     // search depth to all children of top-level windows.
  1066     const int kMaxSearchDepth = 1;
          1067     ui::EnumerateAllWindows(delegate, kMaxSearchDepth);
  1068     return;
  1069   }
  1070   XMenuList::GetInstance()->InsertMenuWindowXIDs(&stack);
  1071 
  1072   std::vector<XID>::iterator iter;
  1073   for (iter = stack.begin(); iter != stack.end(); iter++) {
  1074     if (delegate->ShouldStopIterating(*iter))
  1075       return;
  1076   }
  1077 }
  1078
  ```
- We say they call `delegate->ShouldStopIterating` which was seen in same file as `ScreensaverWindowExists`: http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/source/src/chrome/browser/screensaver_window_finder_x11.cc

  ```
  22 bool ScreensaverWindowFinder::ShouldStopIterating(XID window) {
  23   if (!ui::IsWindowVisible(window) || !IsScreensaverWindow(window))
  24     return false;
  25   exists_ = true;
  26   return true;
  27 }
  ```
- Leads to ask what is `IsWindowVisible` and `IsScreensaverWindow`

*`IsScreensaverWindow`, in same file of `ScreensaverWindowExists`: http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/source/src/chrome/browser/screensaver_window_finder_x11.cc

```
    29 bool ScreensaverWindowFinder::IsScreensaverWindow(XID window) const {
    30   // It should occupy the full screen.
    31   if (!ui::IsX11WindowFullScreen(window))
    32     return false;
    33 
    34   // For xscreensaver, the window should have _SCREENSAVER_VERSION property.
    35   if (ui::PropertyExists(window, "_SCREENSAVER_VERSION"))
    36     return true;
    37 
    38   // For all others, like gnome-screensaver, the window's WM_CLASS property
    39   // should contain "screensaver".
    40   std::string value;
    41   if (!ui::GetStringProperty(window, "WM_CLASS", &value))
    42     return false;
    43 
    44   return value.find("screensaver") != std::string::npos;
    45 }
```

- `IsWindowVisible`: http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/source/src/ui/base/x/x11_util.cc#546

  ```
  546 bool IsWindowVisible(XID window) {
  547   TRACE_EVENT0("ui", "IsWindowVisible");
  548 
  549   XWindowAttributes win_attributes;
  550   if (!XGetWindowAttributes(gfx::GetXDisplay(), window, &win_attributes))
  551     return false;
  552   if (win_attributes.map_state != IsViewable)
  553     return false;
  554 
  555   // Minimized windows are not visible.
  556   std::vector<XAtom> wm_states;
  557   if (GetAtomArrayProperty(window, "_NET_WM_STATE", &wm_states)) {
  558     XAtom hidden_atom = GetAtom("_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN");
  559     if (std::find(wm_states.begin(), wm_states.end(), hidden_atom) !=
  560             wm_states.end()) {
  561       return false;
  562     }
  563   }
  ```

Comment: Massive answer, thanks. I'll play around a bit and this this things out on windows first.

Comment: Hey @BrainFooLong this is answer in works. Its mostly here to guide someone who wants to convert it to js-ctypes or do the implementation in toolkit on bugzilla. I'm kind of interested in seeing this in js-ctypes so kind of motivated to do this myself :P Im just stuck on how to do `addObserver` in Cocoa for Mac OSX.

Comment: @BrainFooLong I can get you windows and linux support right away. would you like that? i would need help for the mac solution. i already posted asking for help about that: https://ask.mozilla.org/question/1296/training-for-js-ctypes-mac-os-x/

Comment: Sure - Would be aweseome when you can implement it for windows and linux. Unfortunetely i'm no firefox core expert and i also don't have a mac to test. Only thing i can do is testing it in my extension when you've done it. I'm not sure how you should integrate that feature but an observer is my first thought for that to get notified when the state has changed.

Comment: The linux and windows implementations arent observers, they have to poll. So every 60sec you can check. Ill look to see if they have a notification method. I hae a final next week so i wont be able to do it this week :(

Comment: No problem. I'll be happy with any solution at any time :)

Comment: @BrainFooLong I figured out how to query if screen is locked via lock or if screensaver is active for osx. Ill write up the windows and linux code and give you something later. final exam tomorrow! in the mean time you can check out the jsctype code for mac, it looks daunting but ill give you a simple fucntion and we'll throw this in a chromeworker: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/ff19ae88500a649c1ef9 and https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/aad68b6fed8ba8d4a429

Comment: Ok windows is also ready: [GitHubGISTS :: Noitidart / _ff-addon-snippet-IsScreenshotRunning.js](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/12bc4ff9f662c1140fef) and [GitHubGISTS :: Noitidart / _ff-addon-snippet-IsWorktationLocked.js](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/06f79f17a8e8a2268a1e). Just have to get linux done now.