# Detecting lock screen on Mac through Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, lockscreen

Trying to find a way to detect if the screen is locked on a Mac system, using Python3

I've tried the following, and it gives a KeyError:

```
import Quartz
gui_dict = Quartz.CGSessionCopyCurrentDictionary()
print(gui_dict['CGSSessionScreenIsLocked'])
```

edit:

```
import Quartz
all_windows = Quartz.CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(Quartz.kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, Quartz.kCGNullWindowID)
for x in all_windows:
    if x["kCGWindowOwnerName"] == "loginwindow"
        print("Locked!")
```

This code works on Python2, but not 3 considering /usr/bin/python needs to be used to import Quartz.

Comment: Rather than voting the question down, it'd be more productive to explain why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install `quartz` -
`pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz`

Much simple code -

```py
import Quartz
d = Quartz.CGSessionCopyCurrentDictionary()
print('CGSSessionScreenIsLocked' in d.keys())
```