# Swift: How to observe if screen is locked in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, quartz

I want to detect if the user has locked his screen (in macOS) using `Swift`.

Based [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505255/osx-check-if-the-screen-is-locked) I’ve created the following code:

```
import Cocoa
import Quartz

if let dict = Quartz.CGSessionCopyCurrentDictionary() as? [String : Any] {
    let locked = dict["CGSSessionScreenIsLocked"]
    print(locked as? String ?? "")
}
```

...which seems to work fine if I explicitly run the code.

**But how is it possible to observe the value so I get notified when the value got changed?**

Comment: Please change the question title accordingly.

Comment: You’re right @Desdenova, I’ve changed it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can observe distributed notifications. They are not documented.

```
let dnc = DistributedNotificationCenter.default()

let lockObserver = dnc.addObserver(forName: .init("com.apple.screenIsLocked"),
                               object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
    NSLog("Screen Locked")
}

let unlockObserver = dnc.addObserver(forName: .init("com.apple.screenIsUnlocked"),
                                 object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
    NSLog("Screen Unlocked")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Combine (available on macOS 10.15+):

```
import Combine

var bag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

let dnc = DistributedNotificationCenter.default()

dnc.publisher(for: Notification.Name(rawValue: "com.apple.screenIsLocked"))
    .sink { _ in print("Screen Locked") }
    .store(in: &bag)

dnc.publisher(for: Notification.Name(rawValue: "com.apple.screenIsUnlocked"))
    .sink { _ in print("Screen Unlocked") }
    .store(in: &bag)
```

Comment: Not working for me, nothing is printed

Comment: @HannesSchneidermayer is your application sandboxed? DistributedNotificationCenter doesn't work with sandboxed applications if I recall correctly.