# Auto fill system user login in MAC OS

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, autofill, macos-app-extension

I have to create a MAC OS desktop application for auto-fill system login.

For that I have checked [AutoFill Credential Provider Entitlement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_authentication-services_autofill-credential-provider), but it works only for AutoFill in Safari and other MAC OS native apps, Didn't works for system login.

Also create desktop app demo to detect [screen lock/unlock events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346761/swift-how-to-observe-if-screen-is-locked-in-macos) using `addObserver` notification center, puts an application in login items, it works after user login into the system, how can I start my desktop app when the system starts before login(start app on the system login screen)

Also i have checked [customized login screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719864/how-to-customize-the-mac-osx-login) field using [NameAndPassword](https://github.com/skycocker/NameAndPassword) plugin, but it works only after user logout from system, it didn't work on mac os start-up and sleep mode, and suggest how can I auto-fill user name and password field from MAC OS desktop app.

My concern is the auto-fill system user login screen username and password field using a custom login screen or default system login screen.

Comment: Do you have FileVault enabled on your test mac, where you are trying the NameAndPassword example?

Comment: I have built a password auto-fill app, and yes it will work with Safari, however I'm not aware of any way of doing this for system login.